# Play Framework Parse error. Unsupported syntax: CONST

Tags: javascript, playframework, constants

On a Play Framework 2 project if I have any javascript code with this simple statements like that:

```
const num = 3;
```

I get the error:
Parse error. Unsupported syntax: CONST

I see that Play Framework has a Javascript Compiler and, from I what I get, minifies your javascript automatically but are consts really not supported ?? It is fundamental language syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that while "const" is reserved as a future keyword by the ECMAScript specification, Mozilla and most other browsers implement it as a non-standard extension that may be standardized in a future version of ECMAScript.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

If you really want it to be non-editable (**I DO NOT RECOMMEND DOING THIS**), you could use getters and setters:

```
window.__defineGetter__('num', function () {
    return 3;
});

window.__defineSetter__('num', function () {
    // nada, it's a constant
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tp2HU/

Answer (score 2):

`const` is reserved for future in JavaScript;
you can not use it.

[JavaScript reserved words](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm)

Comment: Actually `const` is working in Firefox 15.0 and Chrome 21.0. Also Opera won't throw an error, but there is no functionality. IE9 doesn't know `const` at all.